# Jenkins - Gitlab Integration Issue

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration, gitlab, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to integrate Jenkins ver. 2.89.4 with Gitlab 1.5.3
I have entered my Gitlab host URL and 
API Token for accessing Gitlab.
But, when I click test connection, i get the following exception trace:
Any help will be appreciate.

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: no client-builder found that supports server at https://gitlab.com/tom/abc.git
    at com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.gitlab.api.impl.AutodetectingGitLabClient.autodetectOrDie(AutodetectingGitLabClient.java:271)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
Caused: javax.servlet.ServletException
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:765)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: 1. The documentation says the logged in role should be global admin or owner level or master to perform some build operations. Cross check your role and their permissions. 

2. Check the pipeline jobs and any checkboxes that indicate the appropriate build trigger event like a "Build when...". 

3. What is the type of job that you have configured?

4. In travis, that I am more familiar with, there is a .yml file describing the build seq. and an option to whether to build using it ONLY or without it. Are you using any build script?

Comment: Thanks for your time, but the problem was resolved by using the root URL https://gitlab.com and the API Token.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was resolved by the root URL https://gitlab.com and the API Token in the :
Jenkins > configuration > GitLab connections >  Gitlab host URL 
Jenkins > configuration > GitLab connections >  Credentials

I had to create an API from the GitLab repo site. which was applied to Jenkins via :
Jenkins > Credentials > Systems